# Asymmetric encryption and Decryption C#

Tags: c#, encryption, encryption-asymmetric

I have implemented this code for message encryption with public key and decryption with private key..Now i need to change it encryption with private key and decrypted with public key. What should i change in the following code,i am beginner.please help.

```
public static string Encrypt(string plainText, X509Certificate2 certificate)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(plainText))
            throw new ArgumentNullException("plainText");

        using (var aesManaged = new AesManaged())
        {
            aesManaged.KeySize = 256;
            aesManaged.BlockSize = 128;
            aesManaged.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;

            // Create the streams used for encryption.
            using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                // Generate a Symmetric Key used to actually encrypt the data


                RSAPKCS1KeyExchangeFormatter keyFormatter = new RSAPKCS1KeyExchangeFormatter((RSACryptoServiceProvider)certificate.PublicKey.Key);
                byte[] keyEncrypted = keyFormatter.CreateKeyExchange(aesManaged.Key, aesManaged.GetType());

                //byte[] LenSalt = new byte[_saltSize];

                // Create byte arrays to contain
                // the length values of the key and IV.
                byte[] LenK = new byte[_keyBytes];
                byte[] LenIV = new byte[_keyBytes];

                // Salt genration : 
                // default iteration count is 1000 in .NET (this is the same as when using Constructor(string password, int salt))
                //using (var keyDerivationFunction = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(keyEncrypted, LenSalt, _iterations))
                //{
                //    LenSalt = keyDerivationFunction.Salt;
                //}

                int lKey = keyEncrypted.Length;
                LenK = BitConverter.GetBytes(lKey);
                int lIV = aesManaged.IV.Length;
                LenIV = BitConverter.GetBytes(lIV);

                // Write the following to the Stream
                // for the encrypted file (outFs):
                // - length of the key
                // - length of the IV
                // - encrypted key
                // - the IV
                // - the encrypted cipher content
                memoryStream.Write(LenK, 0, 4);
                memoryStream.Write(LenIV, 0, 4);
                //memoryStream.Write(LenSalt, 0, 4);
                memoryStream.Write(keyEncrypted, 0, lKey);
                memoryStream.Write(aesManaged.IV, 0, lIV);
                //memoryStream.Write(LenSalt, 0, _saltSize);

                //using (var encryptor = aesManaged.CreateEncryptor(aesManaged.Key, aesManaged.IV))
                using (var encryptor = aesManaged.CreateEncryptor())
                using (var memoryStreamEnc = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    using (var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStreamEnc, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                    using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(cryptoStream))
                    {
                        // Send the data through the StreamWriter, through the CryptoStream, to the underlying MemoryStream
                        streamWriter.Write(plainText);
                    }
                    memoryStream.Write(memoryStreamEnc.ToArray(), 0, memoryStreamEnc.ToArray().Length);
                }

                return Convert.ToBase64String(memoryStream.ToArray());

            }
        }
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Decrypts the ciphertext using the public key.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="ciphertext">The ciphertext to decrypt.</param>
    /// <param name="certificate">The RSA certificate (need access to Private Key for decryption to work).</param>
    /// <returns>The decrypted text.</returns>
    public static string Decrypt(string ciphertext, X509Certificate2 certificate)
    {
        string outstring = string.Empty;

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ciphertext))
            throw new ArgumentNullException("cipherText");

        if (!certificate.HasPrivateKey)
            throw new ApplicationException("The private key is not accessible.  Decryption is not supported.");


        var allTheBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(ciphertext);

        //using (var keyDerivationFunction = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetString(symmetricKey), saltBytes))
        using (var aesManaged = new AesManaged())
        {

            aesManaged.KeySize = 256;
            aesManaged.BlockSize = 128;
            aesManaged.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;

            // Create byte arrays to get the length of
            // the encrypted key and IV.
            // These values were stored as 4 bytes each
            // at the beginning of the encrypted package.
            byte[] LenK = new byte[_keyBytes];
            byte[] LenIV = new byte[_keyBytes];

            using (MemoryStream InStr = new MemoryStream(allTheBytes))
            {
                InStr.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                InStr.Read(LenK, 0, _keyBytes - 1);
                InStr.Seek(_keyBytes, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                InStr.Read(LenIV, 0, _keyBytes - 1);

                // Convert the lengths to integer values.
                int lenK = BitConverter.ToInt32(LenK, 0);
                int lenIV = BitConverter.ToInt32(LenIV, 0);

                // Determine the start postition of
                // the ciphter text (startC)
                // and its length(lenC).
                int startC = lenK + lenIV + 8;
                int lenC = (int)InStr.Length - startC;

                // Create the byte arrays for
                // the encrypted AesManaged key,
                // the IV, and the cipher text.
                byte[] KeyEncrypted = new byte[lenK];
                byte[] IV = new byte[lenIV];

                // Extract the salt, key and IV
                // starting from index 8
                // after the length values.
                InStr.Seek(8, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                InStr.Read(KeyEncrypted, 0, lenK);
                InStr.Seek(8 + lenK, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                InStr.Read(IV, 0, lenIV);

                byte[] KeyDecrypted = ((RSACryptoServiceProvider)certificate.PrivateKey).Decrypt(KeyEncrypted, false);

                byte[] CipherTextBytes = new byte[lenC];
                InStr.Seek(startC, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                InStr.Read(CipherTextBytes, 0, lenC);

                using (var decryptor = aesManaged.CreateDecryptor(KeyDecrypted, IV))
                using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(CipherTextBytes))
                using (var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(cryptoStream))
                {
                    // Return the decrypted bytes from the decrypting stream.
                    return streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Don't. Encryption with private key and decryption with public key does not make sense, unless you are trying to create your own signature format.

Comment: It is not just that this is a bad idea, but it just doesn't make sense according to the design of the public-key algorithms.  To clarify, Wikipedia calls the two keys ["a public encryption key and a private decryption key"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography#How_it_works).

Comment: Please give me teh codez! The spelling and inclusion of commented-out code in your sample is not going to help your cause, but it's already been said that what you've requested is not logical and maybe you need to re-evaluate your assumptions.

Comment: Three people think this is a great, well researched question... Why?  This is absolutely not what you want to do.  You really should never decrypt with the public key.  Please explain what you want to accomplish so we can help you do what you need to do.

Comment: Dan Maquire - Decryption with public key is used with digital signatures - Any one can read it, but no one can write/change it.

Comment: BTW: The code does not use assymteric cipher. It uses AES which is symmetrical cipher, so no public or private key, but only one (secret) key.